# What is the difference between google tag manager and google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am reading about web analytic and came across GTM and GA.

It seems that GA is a service provided by google which generates reports and statistics on website traffic. As per my limited understanding in order to generate this reports we need to perform some type of tagging at our end.

It also looks like that in GTM also we need to add some tags in our website.

So, if both GA & GTM are related to tagging what is the difference between them and why do we have two different products by google.

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager is mainly for non-developers who aren't comfortable with adding code to their sites. With it you can add one chunk of code to your website, and then manage the various different "tags" that are added through the Google Tag Manager interface, one of which you can add being Google Analytics.

From my limited experience, Google Tag Manager is only really helpful for adding tags related to Google products, so any time you're working outside of the Google ecosystem, you'll end up having to add tags the "old fashioned way" anyway.

As a developer, I've seen very little of use from Google Tag Manager, but non-developers may feel differently.

Comment: If you look at the GTM documentation its implementation includes creating `datalayer` object and populating it with required data. So, it seems to me that  there is fair amount of code invloved for developers and there is no one common chunk of code.

Comment: The last time I looked at it, I thought it was just a chunk of Javascript you put on page.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics shows how users are interacting with your website or app.
Google Tag Manager is a tag management service (TMS) used to simplify tag integration, including tags like Google Analytics pageviews or event tracking.

Generally, GTM is an optional layer used by large websites. One of the main benefits of GTM is automated link tracking. However, it can be quite challenging to learn, so you're better off learning Google Analytics first.